# Trouble with toString method

Tags: java, tostring

Why won't variables basica (Crank) and basicb (Pedal) show up in my arraylist display along with the other values? There's another class called Part which i can post if needed, but it just seems to be ignoring those variables.

Main Class

```
    package main;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestAssembledPart {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<AssembledPart> aparts = new ArrayList<AssembledPart>();
    aparts.add(new AssembledPart("a200", "Crank & Pedal", 10, 3.5, "Crank", "Pedal"));

     System.out.println("part before stock level change - start");
     System.out.println(AssembledPart.toAssembledString(aparts));

}

}
```

AssembledPart class

```
 package main;
 import java.util.*;

public class AssembledPart extends Part {

private String basica;
private String basicb;

public AssembledPart(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice, 
                    String basica, String basicb) {

    super(id, name, stocklevel, unitprice);

    this.basica = basica;
    this.basicb = basicb;
}


public String toAssembledString(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice) {
    return id + " | " + name + " | " + stocklevel + " | " + unitprice + " | " + basica + " | " + basicb;
}

public static String toAssembledString(Collection<AssembledPart> aparts){
    String s = "";
    for (AssembledPart apart: aparts){
        s += apart + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

Part Class

```
  package main;
  import java.util.*;

  public class Part {

private String id;
private String name;
private int stocklevel;
private double unitprice;

private int qty = 6000;

public Part(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.stocklevel = stocklevel;
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
}


String partsAvailable()
{
    //String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    return (id + "\t" + name + "\t    " + stocklevel + "\t\t   " + unitprice);
}


public String getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getStockLevel(){
    return stocklevel - qty;
}

public void setStockLevel(int stocklevel){
    this.stocklevel = stocklevel;
}

public double getUnitPrice(){
    return unitprice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(double unitprice){
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
}

public void replenish(int qty){
    this.stocklevel = stocklevel + qty;
}

public double supply(int qty){
    return unitprice * qty;
}

public String toString() {
    return id + " | " + name + " | " + stocklevel + " | " + unitprice;
}


public static String toString(Collection<Part> parts){
    String s = "";
    for (Part part: parts){
        s += part + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

[image: output]

Comment: could you share your `Part` class, it seems as if you did override `toString` in your `Part` class, but didn´t do so in your `AssembledPart` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not calling toAssembledString() method, you are calling toString() method, which is (I expect) implemented in Part class.

Instead this:

```
for (AssembledPart apart: aparts){
    s += apart + "\n";
```

Do this:

```
for (AssembledPart apart: aparts){
    s += apart.toAssembledString() + "\n";
```

Then, you should avoid parameters in instance methods:

```
public String toAssembledString(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice) {
    return id + " | " + name + " | " + stocklevel + " | " + unitprice + " | " + basica + " | " + basicb;
}
```

Do it as follows:

```
public String toAssembledString() {
    return super.toString() + " | " + basica + " | " + basicb;
}
```

Thanks @Parker_Halo for his comment

Comment: the toAssembledString(...) method has some parameters which make your answer rather difficult

Comment: ohhhh ok cool, thanks. its my first time working with inheritence

Comment: its telling me
       
apart.toAssembledString() needs a parameter

Comment: method toAssembledString() as I wrote it should not need any parameter. @danielb

Comment: whoops my fault. I forgot to remove the paramters from the instance method lol cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is calling Part.toString() and part doesn't have variables basica and basicb. You must call `toAssembledString()` instead of simple parts before printing.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning empty value to string in your 'toAssembledString' method;

```
  String s = "";
```

Whatever you do, it will always return 1 combination since you are doing `s="";`

Declare it as the class variable and just appending it to the older one.

User `StringBuilder`, better here.

Moreover, create a method that will do `s="";` in case when you need to clear the data of the string so that you can re-use that static string for other object else it will append the data in the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toString()` instead of writing your own overloaded `toAssembledString(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice)` if you dont want to change the implementation of `toAssembledString(Collection<AssembledPart> aparts)`'

```
public String toString() {
    return id + " | " + name + " | " + stocklevel + " | " + unitprice + " | " + basica + " | " + basicb;
}
```

Comment: The post has been edited after my answer we can use corresponding getters instead of fields directly then.

Comment: calling `super.toString` should be a more easy way to get the values.

Comment: is it not a good idea to have a class that has inheritance to have private variables? @Parker_Halo

Comment: @danielb it's no problem to extend a class that has private variables, but you won't be able to access id, name stocklevel and unitprice in the class that extends it

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your part class would be looking something like this

```
public class Part {
    String a, b;
    int c;
    double d;

    public Part(String a, String b, int c, double d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner(" | ");
        j.add(a);
        j.add(b);
        j.add(Integer.toString(c));
        j.add(Double.toString(d));
        return j.toString();
    }
}
```

by calling `s += apart + "\n";` you automaticly call the `toString` method of your class, which looks like to be overriden by the `Part` class. to get the desired output for your `AssembledPart` class you should override the `toString` method and add the additional information like this.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringJoiner j = new StringJoiner(" | ");
    j.add(super.toString());
    j.add(basica);
    j.add(basicb);
    return j.toString();
}
```